# PHP Create new array from existing array with some maths calculation on new array [multidimensional]

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
$arrayOne = array(
    0 => array(
        "no"=> "1",
        "value"=>100
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "no"=> "2",
        "value"=>"20"
    )
    2=> array(
        "no"=> "3",
        "value"=>"30"
    )
);
```

I want to create a new array where the:

```
1st new array value = 100+50 (equal to 150, where 50 is an amount that I want to add to the array).
2nd new array value = 20+150 (equal to 170, where 150 is the total of 1st new array)
3rd new array value = 30+170 (equal to 200, where 170 is the total of 2nd new array)
```

Is this doable? The output should be:

```
   $newArrayOne = array(
        0 => array(
            "no"=> "1",
            "value"=>150
        ), 
        1=> array(
            "no"=> "2",
            "value"=>"170"
        )
        2=> array(
            "no"=> "3",
            "value"=>"200"
        )
    );
```

This requirement is a bit too complicated for me. Can anyone just share me the concept, I will try to figure it out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$arrayOne[0]['value'] += 50;
for($i=1; $i<count($arrayOne); $i++) {
    $arrayOne[$i]['value'] += $arrayOne[$i-1]['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *classic* `foreach` loop

```
$arrayOne = //Your array here...

$newArrayOne  = array();
$toAdd = 50;

foreach( $arrayOne as $key => $val ) {
    $newArrayOne[$key] = $val;  //Assign the value to $newArrayOne

    if ( $key === 0 ) $newArrayOne[$key]['value'] += $toAdd;  //Modify the value: If $key is 0, add 50
    else $newArrayOne[$key]['value'] += $newArrayOne[ $key - 1 ]['value'];  //If $key is not 0, add the value of last entry of $newArrayOne
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [no] => 1
            [value] => 150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [no] => 2
            [value] => 170
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [no] => 3
            [value] => 200
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_array = array(
0 => array(
    "no"=> "1",
    "value"=>100
), 
1=> array(
    "no"=> "2",
    "value"=>"20"
),
2=> array(
    "no"=> "3",
    "value"=>"30"
)
);

$to_be_added = 50; //this is what you want to add to your first value

foreach ($first_array as $key => $val){

  $to_be_added = (int)$val['value'] + $to_be_added ; //type casting
  $newArrayOne[$key]['no']= $val['no'];
  $newArrayOne[$key]['value']= $to_be_added; 


}

print_r($newArrayOne);
```

Notice im type casting your values to integers because not all your "value" are integers.

Your output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [no] => 1 [value] => 150 ) [1] => Array ( [no] => 2 [value] => 170 ) [2] => Array ( [no] => 3 [value] => 200 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

$newArray =  $arrayOne;

foreach ($arrayOne as $k => $v) {

```
$newArray[$k]['value'] = ($k == 0) ? array_sum(array_column($arrayOne, 'value')) : $newArray[$k-1]['value'] + $arrayOne[$k]['value'];
```

}

print_r($newArray);

Answer (score 0):

I have made little effort for you. I hope this will work for you.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$arrayOne = array(
    0 => array(
        "no"=> "1",
        "value"=>100
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "no"=> "2",
        "value"=>"20"
    ),
    2=> array(
        "no"=> "3",
        "value"=>"30"
    )
);
$valnewarr = array();
$valdata = 50;
$i = 0;
foreach($arrayOne as $val){
$valdata = $val['value']+$valdata;
$valnewarr['no'] = ++$i;
$valnewarr['value']  = $valdata;
$newArrayOne[] = $valnewarr;
}
print_r($newArrayOne);
?>
```